# Compare two dates, ignoring timeszones

Tags: javascript

I have a variable called `lastMessageTimestamp` which contains string representing a timestamp that is in UTC: "2022-07-07T11:05:53.209"

I need to compare the time now to the time stored `lastMessageTimestamp`.

```
  // returns unix epoch of utc time now
  const nowDateTime = Date.now();
  const lastMessageDateTime = new Date(lastMessageTimestamp);
  const lastMessageUnixEpoch = Date.UTC(
      lastMessageDateTime.getUTCFullYear(), 
      lastMessageDateTime.getUTCMonth(),
      lastMessageDateTime.getUTCDate(), lastMessageDateTime.getUTCHours(),
      lastMessageDateTime.getUTCMinutes(), lastMessageDateTime.getUTCSeconds()
  );
  const difference = (nowDateTime - lastMessageUnixEpoch) / 1000;
```

The problem with this code is when I call `new Date(lastMessageTimestamp);` my timezone is added (GMT+1) so then when I try and create the `lastMessageInUnixEpoch` the timezone is included and my `difference` var is a whole hour out.

How can I get `lastMessageTimestamp` in to a unix timestamp that doesn't include any timezone so that I can compare it to the unix timestamp that is defined on the `nowDateTime`  var?

Comment: just take difference of `nowDateTime` & `lastMessageTimestamp`. or better do [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/RelativeTimeFormat/RelativeTimeFormat#basic_format_usage)

Comment: Hmm, maybe I wasn't clear. lastMessageTimestamp is a string. I updated the question.

Comment: can you provide an example how `lastMessageTimestamp` value looks

Comment: 2022-07-07T11:05:53.209

Comment: I think this sould solve your issue. `console.log((nowDateTime - lastMessageDateTime) / 1000) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `new Date(lastMessageTimestamp + 'Z')` to ensure it's interpreted as an UTC timestamp:

```
const nowDate = new Date();
const lastMessageDate = new Date(lastMessageTimestamp+'Z');
const difference = (nowDate.getTime() - lastMessageDate.getTime()) / 1000;
```

or

```
const nowDateMillis = Date.now();
const lastMessageDateMillis = Date.parse(lastMessageTimestamp+'Z');
const difference = (nowDateMillis - lastMessageDateMillis) / 1000;
```